# Canvas Image rearrangement and rotation (center)

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

Canvas has an image and rectangle. Image should be rotated around center of canvas therefore I use translate to achive center but translate won't allow to drag the objects(dont know why).

**When I drag, image and rectangle should be draggable together. When I rotate, only image should be rotatable and rectangle should be static(intact to rotation).**

Anyone can help on the following code?

```js
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
                    var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
                    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
                    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    
                    var startX;
                    var startY;
                    var isDown = false;
    
    
                    var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
                    var resizerRadius = 6;
                    var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
                    var draggingResizer = {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0
                    };
                    var imageX = 0;
                    var imageY = 0;
                    var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
                    var draggingImage = false;
                    var startX;
                    var startY;
    
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                        imageWidth = img.width;
                        imageHeight = img.height;
                        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
                        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
                        draw();
                    }
                    img.src = "http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_128.png";
    
                    var x = canvas.width / 2, y = canvas.height / 2;
    
                    function draw() {
                        canvas.width = canvas.width;
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        ctx.save();
                        
                        //I have problem here!
                        //ctx.translate(x + imageX, y + imageY);
    
                        ctx.rotate($('#rvalue').val() * Math.PI / 180);
                        ctx.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY);
                        ctx.restore();
                        
                        ctx.rect(imageX + 160, imageY + 30, 120, 40);
                        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
    
    
                    function hitImage(x, y) {
                        return (x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
                    }
    
    
                    function handleMouseDown(e) {
                        startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                        startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
                        draggingImage = hitImage(startX, startY);
                    }
    
                    function handleMouseUp(e) {
                        draggingImage = false;
                        draw();
                    }
    
                    function handleMouseOut(e) {
                        handleMouseUp(e);
                    }
    
                    function handleMouseMove(e) {
                        if (draggingImage) {
                            imageClick = false;
                            mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                            mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
                            var dx = mouseX - startX;
                            var dy = mouseY - startY;
                            imageX += dx;
                            imageY += dy;
                            imageRight += dx;
                            imageBottom += dy;
                            startX = mouseX;
                            startY = mouseY;
                            draw();
                        }
                    }
    
    
                    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e) {
                        handleMouseDown(e);
                    });
                    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) {
                        handleMouseMove(e);
                    });
                    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e) {
                        handleMouseUp(e);
                    });
                    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e) {
                        handleMouseOut(e);
                    });
                    $("#rotate").click(function(event) {
                        var c = parseInt($('#rvalue').val());
                        $('#rvalue').val(c + 90);
                        draw();
                    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html lang="en"><head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">#canvas { border: 1px solid #000; }</style> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type=text value="0" id="rvalue" />
            <button id=rotate>Rotate</button><br>
                <canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty with canvas, but would it help to translate, rotate, translate back, and THEN draw?

```
ctx.translate( centerx, centery );
ctx.rotate( $('#rvalue').val() * Math.PI / 180 );
ctx.translate( -centerx, -centery );

ctx.drawImage(img, imageX, imageY);
```

Comment: Thanks @WonderfulDay, simplistic approach.! have a great day